# Azure Pipeline Build Agent using subst

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, tfs-migration

We are moving from TFS on Prem to hosted Azure Devops.
In our build we have a script with the following line:

```
subst E: <my path>
```

Sadly the E: is not being mapped to.

We call `subst E: /D` before hand to make sure the path is no there first.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent?

Comment: Yes we are using a hosted agent

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `subst` doesn't work on the hosted agent. Try running your pipelines without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can successfully associate a path with a drive letter with `subst` command in hosted agent. See below example:

```
- powershell: |
   subst Z: D:\a
   Z:
   ls
```

Output :

[image]

If the `path` you were trying to map to `E` didnot exist in the hosted agent. The mapping will fail.

Please make sure the `path` you were trying to map exists.